# Enabling service sharing in ArcGis Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, map-service, security

I am an admin for my organization. I enabled both `Allow Anonymous Access` and `Member can share content publicly` under the security panel. I am trying to connect a webservice we host that is in an unsecured folder. Every time I try to change the sharing on the Map Image Layer I am presented with a blank option. I can't change old services sharing options either - even ones that I somehow managed to set as `shared publicly` before.

I am not sure what is broken in my configuration or if ESRI changed something.

My services come from server 10.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer had nothing to do with ESRI or server configs or anything you would logically think of. It had to do with my chrome browser using Ad Blocker. The popup for those settings was being blocked. You can disable Ad Blocker or use another browser if you run into this issue.